# django template array element access

Tags: python, django

hi:
  day_records is a array , i want to access element of it.if i replace the **point** with 0,or 1 , it's right , but when i use point , it can't access the element ,and with no syntax error.

```
plant.bind("plothover",
       function(event,pos,item){
       if(item){
           removeTooltip();
           var point = item.dataIndex;           
           showTooltip(item.pageX,item.pageY,"{{day_records.point.date}}");
       }else{
           removeTooltip();
       }
       });
```

so ,how can i access the array element with the point varable ?

Comment: I think there's some confusion here...you're mixing django templating and javascript as if they can share data 2-way.  What happens is that {{day_records.point.date}} is evaluated in the context of the django template, and then after a browser gets the page, the javascript is evaluated.  The template can insert data into the javascript, but the javascript can't evaluate django templating code - by the time javascript is run, the templating code is gone.

Comment: My answer would just repeat what Aaron says.. (Hint hint aaron! :P)
Besides, even if that were all django template code, you can't do variable resolved lookups like that. day_records.point would try to find attributes, indexes, etc for 'point' but not what `point` resolves to such as 0 or 1.

Comment: so , could i access javasript variable in django templet ?

Comment: No, they are completely separate. Javascript only runs when the browser loads it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your template code runs completely independently of JavaScript.

The browser runs JavaScript when the page loads, based on whatever raw code your template produced.

Generate a JavaScript array via the template language that your script can use, or use AJAX to request the data from django for a given point.

```
day_records = new Array();
{% for point in day_records %}
    day_records[{{ forloop.counter0 }}] = '{{ point.date }}';
{% endfor %}

plant.bind("plothover",
       function(event,pos,item){
       if(item){
           removeTooltip();
           var point = item.dataIndex;           
           showTooltip(item.pageX,item.pageY, day_records[point]);
       }else{
           removeTooltip();
       }
       });
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried various things whn I stumbled upon this issue. I tried the dot it didn't give me what I wanted. I knew it had to be a dot style since django documentation said so.

I had a list variable like this:   `food = [{'rice':90},{'beans':56},{'peas':144}]`

Finally, what worked was: 
`food.0.rice` 
gives me the number I wanted (for rice),
`food.0.beans` gave me what number was for beans.

I went further to experiment
`food = [
[{'rice':90},{'beans':56}],
[{'banana':90},{'groundnuts':56}]
]`
I could access groundnuts value as `food.1.groundnuts` since it is the 2nd array element
I hope somebody will value this